# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^n\,n!}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the following series convergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^n\,n!}{n^n}$$

I treid the Ratio and Root tests, but both of them failed.

Comment: Hint:  [Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) tells us that $n!\sim \left( \frac ne \right)^n\sqrt {2\pi n}$

Comment: No. One may prove this using the [Term Test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your series is not convergent. Note that $$e^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{k!}>\frac{n^{n}}{n!} \implies e^{n}>\frac{n^{n}}{n!}$$
From the [series expansion of $e^x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Derivatives_and_differential_equations). Multiplying $\dfrac{n!}{n^n}$ on each side, we have that
$$\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}>1 $$
Thus, by comparison test we have that the series diverges.

Comment: would you say, how by comparison test?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi Each terms are larger than $1$......But $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1 $ diverges...

Comment: How do you check the  necessary condition for the series to converge?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi I don't think that relates to my answer. If $a_{n}>1$ for all $n$, is a sufficient condition for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ to diverge. So, we just do comparison. We don't need the necessary condition.

Comment: Wonderfully done! (+1)